# Ubuntu 20.04 5.11.0-40-generic => ALERT! UUID=... does not exist!

Tags: boot, 20.04, macbook, mac-mini

After auto updating the kernel from 5.11.0-38-generic to 5.11.0-40-generic my system won't boot
My computers are

- Apple Mac mini 2019 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700B CPU @ 3.20GHz) and Apple Macbook pro 2019
- Linux is installed on a "WD My Passport SSD 500 GB externe SSD" on partition /dev/sda2

The problems occur with both systems. I have tried to boot with a fresh installation Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3. It ships with kernel 5.11.0-27. After Updating to 5.11.0-43 the same problem occurs.

I get following error messages:

```
Begin: Waiting for root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/local-block ... done.
done
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=e373b7f7-deb5-4265-9699-f36a857daeb9 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
...
```

As described I tried to set rootdelay=90 in rEFInd boot options editor. But this doesn't fix the problem.

EDIT: It seems that there is no access to the external drive.

```
(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
ro root=UUID=e373b7f7-deb5-4265-9699-f36a857daeb9 initrd=boot\initrd.img-5.11.0-40-generic
```

```
(initramfs) blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="5F66-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="52afc870-985c-4c7d-9025-653fd071a434"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="79934026-e0f0-417a-be7a-f2292082fdea" TYPE="apfs" PARTUUID="4df0b3ec-ba74-4381-b43c-c32725f368cb"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="34F5EE1202469FF7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b33219f8-db08-4c44-9d3b-b08989b10f9c"
```

When I boot the system with kernel 5.11.0-38 the output of blkid looks like

```
sudo blkid
/dev/sda2: UUID="e373b7f7-deb5-4265-9699-f36a857daeb9" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ac7c144c-cc01-4af8-922f-40021a28c643"
...
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="5F66-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="52afc870-985c-4c7d-9025-653fd071a434"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="79934026-e0f0-417a-be7a-f2292082fdea" TYPE="apfs" PARTUUID="4df0b3ec-ba74-4381-b43c-c32725f368cb"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="34F5EE1202469FF7" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="b33219f8-db08-4c44-9d3b-b08989b10f9c"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="EFI" LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="6d157669-6d30-48b0-abb9-5b4616445e25"
/dev/sda3: UUID="e9c6e424-ff06-49e4-ad9a-b3afad7afebf" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="76a6b530-bcae-4d91-a64e-6901b42f901a"
...
```

Comment: Please add the output of the commands: cat /proc/cmdline  and of sudo blkid to your original posting.  Is the UUID used in cmdline the one in your error message (that would be from your /boot/grub/grub.cfg)?  Another place the sda2 UUID is used is the 3 line stub grub.cfg file in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu.grub.cfg -- is that one correct?

Answer (score 0):

Last week the auto updater installed kernel version 5.13.0-27-generic and everything is working again. Unfortunately I still don't understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be 100% positive, but you probably encountered a bug/regression in the 5.11.0-43 kernel. These can crop up from time to time -- a bug is introduced in a driver (or a critical driver is somehow omitted from a specific build), resulting in an inability to access some hardware device or some other problem.

Another possibility is that there was a problem when building the initramfs for the kernel in question. This could, again, be because of a bug; or it could be something like a disk that filled up or even filesystem damage that caused corruption to a critical file.

In either case, the solution is to not use the affected kernel. Beginning with the first time the kernel is updated, Ubuntu should always keep at least two kernels in `/boot`, including the one that was booted most recently. Thus, you should be able to boot a good kernel even when a kernel update causes problems. In rEFInd, you can do this by hitting Tab, Insert, or F2 after you highlight the Linux kernel; this produces a submenu that gives you access both to variant options for booting the primary kernel and options to boot other (usually older) kernels. If an older kernel works but a newer one doesn't, you can make the older kernel the default by using the `touch` command in Linux. You'll need to do this with `sudo`, as in:

```
sudo touch /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic
```

This kernel will then become the default when you select the Linux kernel in rEFInd.

When using GRUB, you can select any kernel you like from the GRUB menu. If GRUB doesn't normally display this menu, you can get it to display by hitting the Shift key (IIRC) as GRUB starts up -- so basically, just keep repeatedly hitting Shift as soon as you turn on the computer. To change the default in GRUB, you'd have to edit its configuration files, and I'm afraid I don't recall the details of what you'd need to change.